# Handle multiple errors when the user fill inputs in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm pretty new with Kotlin (and also I've never coded in Java), and I want to know if there is another way to to this, or if its okay.

To put you in context, I'm working with the Model-View-Presenter. The presenter here, receives the username and login from the login screen, and in order to handle errors (such as empty fields, invalid email), I created an Enum (with possible errors), and then I fill the list of these errors by checking conditions.

Presenter:

```
fun onLoginButtonClicked(email: String, password: String) {
        val errorEnum = mutableListOf<ErrorEnum>()
        if (email.isEmpty()) errorEnum.add(ErrorEnum.EMPTY_EMAIL)
        if (password.isEmpty()) errorEnum.add(ErrorEnum.EMPTY_PASSWORD)
        if (email.isNotEmpty() && !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) errorEnum.add(ErrorEnum.INVALID_EMAIL)

        if (errorEnum.isEmpty()) {
            userSession.email = email
            userSession.password = password
            view?.goToViewPager(email)
        } else {
            view?.checkErrors(errorEnum)
        }
    }
```

After that, the fragment reflects on the view the errors, iterating through the list.

Fragment:

```
override fun checkErrors(Errors: MutableList<ErrorEnum>) {
        Errors.forEach {
            when (it) {
                ErrorEnum.EMPTY_PASSWORD -> binding.password.error = getString(R.string.login_alert_input)
                ErrorEnum.INVALID_EMAIL -> binding.email.error = getString(R.string.login_alert_bad_email)
                ErrorEnum.EMPTY_EMAIL -> binding.email.error = getString(R.string.login_alert_input)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i don't think stack overflow deals with coding reviews, if that's what you're asking for here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, you are doing redundant work here, first your are building up `List` and then passing the `List` to `View` and again `View` is doing some work to iterate and compare, instead you can have separate methods in view to handle each without comparison and call them directly

```
override fun showEmailInvalidError() {
   binding.password.error = getString(R.string.login_alert_input)
}
override fun showEmptyEmailError() {
   binding.email.error = getString(R.string.login_alert_input)
}
override fun showEmptyPasswordError() {
  binding.email.error = getString(R.string.login_alert_bad_email)
}
```

In presenter

```
fun onLoginButtonClicked(email: String, password: String) {
    if(email.isEmpty()) view?.showEmptyEmailError()
    if(password.isEmpty()) view?.showEmptyPasswordError()
    if(email.isNotEmpty() && !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
        view?.showEmailInvalidError()

    if(errorEnum.isEmpty()) {
        userSession.email = email
        userSession.password = password
        view?.goToViewPager(email)
    }else {
        view?.checkErrors(errorEnum)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right! This seems better. Perhaps this is beyond the scope of the current question but, in a situation when I have to check more empty fields (like 20 fields), the only way to achieve this is by adding methods to the view?

Comment: Ideally yes, also with bundling errors for such huge forms is not a good UX, input should be validated and errors should be notified to user as they type instead of making them wait to fill everything and then throwing all the errors at one time.